# does angular have a way to parseInt inside templates?

Tags: angular

In this scenario, the `<li>` tag will never have an active class because `currentPage` is coming from the url query params and therefore a string, and the page it is comparing against is a number.

```
<ul *ngIf="(route.queryParams | async).page as currentPage">
  <li *ngRepeat="let page of pages" [ngClass]="{ 'active': page === currentPage }">{{ page }}</li>
</ul>
```

Angular won't let me do:

```
<ul *ngIf="Number((route.queryParams | async).page) as currentPage">
```

or

```
<ul *ngIf="parseInt((route.queryParams | async).page) as currentPage">
```

... Is there a way to accomplish this without having to write my own function to convert?

Comment: Write a pipe for it: `| parseInt`

Comment: Nope, function calls in the template implicitly refer to component methods - it's the same as writing `this.parseInt(...)`. Just make a class method or a pipe for it.

Comment: just use the "+" to convert a string as number:`*ngIf="+(route.queryParams | async).page as currentPage"`